# Get Battery Level on App Launch

Tags: android, batterylevel

In My app, I'm using **"ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED"** intent to find battery level of the Android device.

** Problem:**

consider If the device is having 1-20 as  battery level, I need to show low battery icon in my application.I'm not able to show immediately

I have registered the broadcast receiver for **ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED** Intent on app launch itself. Since this is System wide announcement, I am not able to get immediately.

Can I trigger Broadcast for **ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED** Intent using SendBroadcast() on App Launch?

Is this a correct behavior?

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko,My question is get battery level on app lauch

Comment: I know that, I read that in the question. But looks like you didn't check the question I've linked. Please do.

Comment: @kavie So? use the method that gets battery percentage in your starter activity?

Answer (score 0):

Best way of get battery level is

```
           String currentBatteryStatus = "Battery Percentage";
            int deviceStatus = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_STATUS, -1);
            int level = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL, -1);
            int scale = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_SCALE, -1);
            int batteryLevel = (int) (((float) level / (float) scale) * 100.0f);

            if (deviceStatus == BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_CHARGING) {
                currentBatteryStatus = currentBatteryStatus + " Charging : " + batteryLevel + " %";
            }

            if (deviceStatus == BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_DISCHARGING) {
                currentBatteryStatus = currentBatteryStatus + " Discharging : " + batteryLevel + " %";
            }

            if (deviceStatus == BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_FULL) {
                currentBatteryStatus = currentBatteryStatus + " Battery Full : " + batteryLevel + " %";
            }

            if (deviceStatus == BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_UNKNOWN) {
                currentBatteryStatus = currentBatteryStatus + " Unknown : " + batteryLevel + " %";
            }

            if (deviceStatus == BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_NOT_CHARGING) {
                currentBatteryStatus = currentBatteryStatus + " Not Charging : " + batteryLevel + " %";
            }
```

If you have any questions then ask me

Comment: where to get that `intent`?

Comment: From Receive, If you need full code then i'll edit my code

Comment: and the question is exactly about how to get this info on app start, not when battery status changes. Please make sure that you read and understand the question before answerring

Comment: Yes we can use same code for app start just , trigger this code by Application class

Comment: Yeah I have registered in application class's onCreate() and Unregistering in onTerminate()

Comment: @kavie Okay then create broadcast receiver Trigger that from application on create and save data if you want, and kill broadcast after recover your data

Answer (score -1):

ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED is sticky intent and as soon as you register a receiver for this broadcast you should be getting last modified value of it.
It seems like its issue with your broadcast setup. You can do it like this:

```
    BroadcastReceiver powerReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
                @Override
                public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                    int level = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL, 0);
                    Logger.e("Power", "Battrery NOW " + String.valueOf(level) + "%");
                    //Your logic here

                }
            };

            @Override
            public void onResume() {
                super.onResume();
                getBaseActivity().registerReceiver(powerReceiver,
                        new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED));    
            }

            @Override
            public void onPause() {
                super.onPause();
                getBaseActivity().unregisterReceiver(powerReceiver);
            }
```

Comment: please make sure you read the question before answering